# Program that determines average course grade

Tags: c

This program is supposed to take a text file containing students quiz grades and write it into another file containing the student name and assign a grade to the student

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void format(FILE *outputFile);
void copyNames(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile);
void copyScores(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile);

int main(int arc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *inputScores, *averageScores;
    inputScores = fopen("quiz.txt", "r");
    averageScores = fopen("average.txt", "w");

    if (inputScores == NULL || averageScores == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: The file(s) could not be opened!");
        return(1);
    }


    copyNames(inputScores, averageScores);
    copyScores(inputScores, averageScores);

    fclose(inputScores);
    fclose(averageScores);

    return 0;
}


void copyNames(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
    char firstName[10], lastName[10], ch;
    ch = fgetc(inputFile); //sets ch to a place in the file
    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET); //resets ch so it is at the beginning of the file
    while (ch != EOF){
        int i = 0, j = 0; //resets values in the array so you can overwrite it
        for (ch = fgetc(inputFile); ch != ' ' && ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(inputFile)){ //gets the first name and puts it into an array
            firstName[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        for (ch = fgetc(inputFile); ch != ' ' && ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(inputFile)){ //gets last name and puts it into array
            lastName[j] = ch;
            j++;
        }
        lastName[j] = '\0'; //truncates the arrays
        firstName[i] = '\0';
        while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF){ //moves the placement of ch to avoid all the grades to get the next name
            ch = fgetc(inputFile);
        }
        fprintf(outputFile, "%s, %s \n", lastName, firstName); //prints the names to the output file
    }
}

void copyScores(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET); //resets fgetc again
    char lineMemory[60], sc = fgetc(inputFile);
    while (sc != EOF){
        int i = 0, num = 0, scores[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        for (sc = fgetc(inputFile); sc != '\n' && sc != EOF; sc = fgetc(inputFile)){ //writes the whole line into an array
            lineMemory[i] = sc;
            i++;
        }
        lineMemory[i] = '\0'; //truncates the array
        for (int check = 0; lineMemory[check] != '\0'; check++){ //walks through the string
            if (isdigit(lineMemory[check]) != 0){ //looks for the digits in the string
                int j = lineMemory[check] - '0'; //turns the characters into integers
                scores[num] = j; //puts the integer into the array
                num++;
            }
        }
        float avg, total = 0;
        for (int indx = 0; indx < 10; indx++){
            total += scores[indx];
        }
        avg = total / 10; //finds average of the grades
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            fprintf(outputFile, "%2d", scores[x]); //prints the quiz grades
        }
        fprintf(outputFile, "%10g\n", avg); //prints the average
    }
}

void copyAll(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
    char ch = fgetc(inputFile);

    while (ch != EOF){
        ch = fgetc(inputFile);
        fputc(ch, outputFile);
    }
    printf("Data successfully written.\n");
}
```

The results is supposed to be like:

```
 Alex Smith 98 100 90 82 92.5
 john Adams 100 90 82 90 90.5
 //92.5 and 90.5 being the average.
```

But my code just displays the name altogether and the grades underneath the names. like:

```
 Alex Smith
 john adams
 98 100 90 
 100 90 82 etc...
```

Comment: 1. Read name, 2. read scores, 3. compute average, 4. write name & average to output file. 5. Repeat 1..4 until end-of-input. That's the algorithm. Now considering that, how is your code *different* than that algorithm.  [Explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Are you supposed to **not** use `fscanf()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you cannot handle names and scores in 2 separate loops, for the expected output you must handle one line at a time.
- `fgetc()` returns an `int`, do not assign it to a `char` or you will be unable to reliably detect `EOF`.
- you call `fgetc()` too many times. You should use a combined read and test idiom:

  ```
  void copyAll(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
      int ch ;

      while ((ch = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF) {
          fputc(ch, outputFile);
      }
      printf("Data successfully written.\n");
  }
  ```
- you never check for potential buffer overflows: invalid input will cause undefined behavior.
- the code in `copyScores` to convert scores into numbers is incorrect: it can only handle single digit scores.
- you output the scores with `"%2d"`, which would not separate scores greater than `9`. Use `" %d"` instead.
- you read `num` scores but always output 10 scores and their average.
- the calls `fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);` are useless. They are only needed for streams open in update mode, which are very tricky to use correctly.

Here is a much simpler version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *input, *output;
    char firstname[50], lastname[50];
    int score, n, total;

    input = fopen("quiz.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("average.txt", "w");
    if (input == NULL || output == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: The file(s) could not be opened!");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(input, "%49s%49s", firstname, lastname) == 2) {
        fprintf(output, "%s %s", firstname, lastname);
        for (n = 0, total = 0; fscanf(input, "%d", &score) == 1; n++) {
            fprintf(output, " %d", score);
            total += score;
        }
        fprintf(output, " %.2f\n", n == 0 ? 0.0 : (double)total / n);
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " fprintf(" %.2f\n", n == 0 ? 0.0 : (double)total / n); " should be " fprintf(output," %.2f\n", n == 0 ? 0.0 : (double)total / n); "

Comment: @Whozcry: good point! corrected.