# Program that determines average quiz grade

Tags: c

This program is supposed to take a text file containing students quiz grades and write it into another file containing the student name and assign a grade to the student

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void format(FILE *outputFile);
void copyNames(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile);
void copyScores(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *input, *output;
    char firstname[50], lastname[50];
    int score, n, total;

    input = fopen("quiz.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("average.txt", "w");
    if (input == NULL || output == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: The file(s) could not be opened!");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(input, "%49s%49s", firstname, lastname) == 2) {
        fprintf(output, "%s %s", firstname, lastname);
        for (n = 0, total = 0; fscanf(input, "%d", &score) == 1; n++) {
            fprintf(output, " %d", score);
            total += score;
        }
        fprintf(output, " %.2f\n", n == 0 ? 0.0 : (double)total / n);
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}


void copyNames(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
    char firstName[10], lastName[10], ch;
    ch = fgetc(inputFile); //sets ch to a place in the file
    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET); //resets ch so it is at the beginning of the file
    while (ch != EOF){
        int i = 0, j = 0; //resets values in the array so you can overwrite it
        for (ch = fgetc(inputFile); ch != ' ' && ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(inputFile)){ //gets the first name and puts it into an array
            firstName[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        for (ch = fgetc(inputFile); ch != ' ' && ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(inputFile)){ //gets last name and puts it into array
            lastName[j] = ch;
            j++;
        }
        lastName[j] = '\0'; //truncates the arrays
        firstName[i] = '\0';
        while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF){ //moves the placement of ch to avoid all the grades to get the next name
            ch = fgetc(inputFile);
        }
        fprintf(outputFile, "%s, %s \n", lastName, firstName); //prints the names to the output file
    }
}

void copyScores(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET); //resets fgetc again
    char lineMemory[60], sc = fgetc(inputFile);
    while (sc != EOF){
        int i = 0, num = 0, scores[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        for (sc = fgetc(inputFile); sc != '\n' && sc != EOF; sc = fgetc(inputFile)){ //writes the whole line into an array
            lineMemory[i] = sc;
            i++;
        }
        lineMemory[i] = '\0'; //truncates the array
        for (int check = 0; lineMemory[check] != '\0'; check++){ //walks through the string
            if (isdigit(lineMemory[check]) != 0){ //looks for the digits in the string
                int j = lineMemory[check] - '0'; //turns the characters into integers
                scores[num] = j; //puts the integer into the array
                num++;
            }
        }
        float avg, total = 0;
        for (int indx = 0; indx < 10; indx++){
            total += scores[indx];
        }
        avg = total / 10; //finds average of the grades
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            fprintf(outputFile, "%2d", scores[x]); //prints the quiz grades
        }
        fprintf(outputFile, "%10g\n", avg); //prints the average
    }
}

void copyAll(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
    char ch = fgetc(inputFile);

    while (ch != EOF){
        ch = fgetc(inputFile);
        fputc(ch, outputFile);
    }
    printf("Data successfully written.\n");
}
```

> ```
> Smith, Alex    98 100 90 82 92.5
> Adams, John    100 90 82 90 90.5
> ```
>
> `//`with four spaces between the name and the averages
>    `//`92.5 and    90.5 being the average.

But my code just displays the name altogether and the grades underneath the names. like:

> ```
> Alex Smith
> john adams
> 98 100 90 
> 100 90 82
> ```
>
> etc...

Comment: Need an [mcve] which includes the input file, expected output, and output your code generates. 1. You did not define the expected input, which is important.  2. why did you write `copyNames`, `copyScores`, and `copyAll`?  I don't see where you call these functions or why you need them for your question.  3. Your code looks very well written, and looks like it will generate the first output (except for the 4 spaces), which is what I assume you are after.  But this depends on the input.

Comment: Did you write this code? It is some of the most well written C code I've seen from a beginner.

Comment: `ch` needs to be an int and not a char because `fgetc` returns an int.

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988293/program-that-determines-average-course-grade

Answer (score 2):

> But my code just displays the name altogether and the grades underneath the names. like:

I'm afraid the posted code no longer has this output: you copied [my answer's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988293/program-that-determines-average-course-grade/55990234#55990234) as a replacement for your `main` function, which should have a much closer output to what is expected than previously. But you should:

- remove the other functions which have become useless
- slightly adjust the `printf` to match the updated problem statement:

  ```
  fprintf(output, "%s, %s   ", lastname, firstname);
  ```
- adjust the average `printf` to output a single decimal:

  ```
  fprintf(output, " %.1f\n", n == 0 ? 0.0 : (double)total / n);
  ```

Note however that the problem statement is inconsistent:

> ```
> Smith, Alex    98 100 90 82 92.5
> Adams, John    100 90 82 90 90.5
> ```
>
> with four spaces between the name and the averages
>    `92.5` and `90.5` being the average.

The 4 spaces appear between the first name and the first grade, he average appears after all grades, separated from the last grade by a single space.